# How to add cart items in local storage and how can I receive it on my cart page and show it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have done this for storing my cart item in local storage. from my ProductDetails.js

```
   const addProduct = (product) => {
    dispatch(addToCart(product));
    localStorage.setItem("cartItem", product.id);
  };
```

And i am using this code for retrieving from local storage using key "cartItem" in my MyCart.js
and when i press the items 2 time it adds the item only once in the cart.

```
useEffect(() => {    
    const cartItem = localStorage.getItem("cartItem");
    if (cartItem) {
      const parsedCartItem = JSON.parse(cartItem);
   dispatch(addToCart(parsedCartItem));
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
```

[But when i am recieveing it on MyCart.js it is showing like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oRYN.png)

and when i am reloading the page the cart becomes Empty. Can anyone please provide me a solution for this.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeFromCart, addToCart } from "../Redux/action/action";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const MyCart = () => {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state.handleCart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Retrieve the item from local storage
    const cartItem = localStorage.getItem("cartItem");

    // Parse the item if it exists in local storage
    if (cartItem) 
      const parsedCartItem = JSON.parse(cartItem);
      // You can dispatch an action to add this item to your Redux state if needed
      dispatch(addToCart(parsedCartItem));
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleClose = (item) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(item));
  };

  const cartItems = (cartItem) => {
    return (
      <div className="px-4 my-5 bg-light rounded-3" key={cartItem.id}>
        <div className="container py-4">
          <button
            className="btn-close float-end"
            aria-label="Close"
            onClick={() => handleClose(cartItem)}
          ></button>

          <div className="d-flex row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <img
                src={cartItem.image}
                alt={cartItem.title}
                height="200px"
                width="180px"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4 ">
              <h3> {cartItem.title} </h3>
              <p className="lead"> {cartItem.description} </p>
              <p className="lead fw-bolder">${cartItem.price}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const emptyCart = () => {
    return (
      <div className="my-4 px-3 bg-light rounded-3 ">
        <div className="container py-4 ">
          <div className="row">
            <h3>Your Card is Empty</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const button = () => {
    return (
      <div className="container ">
        <div className="row">
          <NavLink
            to="/checkout"
            className="btn mb-5 btn-outline-primary w-25 mx-auto"
          >
            Checkout
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {state.length === 0 && emptyCart()}

      {state.length !== 0 && state.map(cartItems)}
      {state.length !== 0 && button()}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyCart;
```

This is my reducer

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from "../action/action-type";

const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],

};

const handleCart = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log("Current State:", state);
  const product = action.payload;
  console.log("Action type:", action.type);

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const existingProduct = state.cartItems.find(
        (item) => item.id === product.id
      );

      if (existingProduct) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((item) =>
            item.id === product.id
              ? {
                  ...item,
                  qty: item.qty + 1,
                }
              : item
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [
            ...state.cartItems,
            {
              ...product,
              qty: 1,
            },
          ],
        };
      }

    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      const existingProductToRemove = state.cartItems.find(
        (item) => item.id === product.id
      );
      if (existingProductToRemove.qty === 1) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((item) => item.id !== product.id),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((item) =>
            item.id === product.id
              ? {
                  ...item,
                  qty: item.qty - 1,
                }
              : item
          ),
        };
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default handleCart;
```

I am expecting the cart to show the items present in local storage.

Comment: It might be useful to see the implementation of the "addToCart" action. Also can we see how you save the data to the localStorage?

Comment: In addProduct(), you are setting the cartItem as the product.id. This should be set to the product I would imagine.

Comment: i have update my code above addtocart()

Comment: The only truth lays within `state` or `state.cartItems`. The cart items view gets rendered from it, and adding/removing products to/from it does update all cart item related data. Thus, whenever a state change happens the `JSON.stringify`-ed version of e.g. the entire `cartItems` array has to be locally stored under one and the same storage key again and again.